# Is there a way on Google Drive API to get the file id from webContentLink property?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

In firebase storage, for instance, you can get the reference of the file from just the download url with a method called refFromURL(). Is there a way to do the same thing on google drive api? Like obtaining the file id just with the webContentLink value?

Comment: Those files were previously uploaded from an existing google api key, we are still using it? We saved the webContentLink value after uploading but not the file id. We realized now that we need to manage those files, so I'm wondering if there is a way to get the file id from that webContentLink value.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*The file ID is inside the `webContentLink` value.*

#### More Information:

Let's say for example you have `webContentLink` data such as:

```
{
 "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1jz7Xl_OonGdlVd2QqOiPIr2KU_0BtZ-A&export=download"
}
```

The part between the `id=` and the `&export` is the file ID:

```
1jz7Xl_OonGdlVd2QqOiPIr2KU_0BtZ-A
```

Note: Only non-Google Workspace files have `webContentLink`s (images, videos, `.xlsx` files, etc). You can not do this for native Sheets/Docs/Slides files.